# python can not split serial.readline

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port

i try to save a string, send by my board, but i can't save the TC[1]'s data, it always error: IndexError: list index out of range

here is the board send's data

```
[TC]4915 31[TC]
[TC]4916 77[TC]
[TC]4917 23[TC]
[TC]4918 69[TC]
[TC]4919 15[TC]
```

and here is my code

```
import serial
TC = []
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)  
while 1:
    string = ser.readline()
    string = string.strip()
    string = string.replace("[TC]","")
    TC = string.split(" ",2)
    print TC[1]
```

but when i used

```
TC = []
string = "[TC]4915 31[TC]"
string = string.strip()
string = string.replace("[TC]","")
TC = string.split(" ",2)
print TC[1]
```

it's work

so what's wrong?

2016/02/18

Hey Gus!I try to print ser.readline() it can be split

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600)  
while 1:
    string = ser.readline()
    print str(ser.readline().strip().replace("[TC]",'')).split(' ')[0] 
    print str(ser.readline().strip().replace("[TC]",'')).split(' ')[1]
```

but the answer look like

```
1385
97
1388
35
1391
73
1394
11
1397
49
1400
87
1403
25
```

can't catch each data, and i also try

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600)  
while 1:
    string = ser.readline()
    print str(ser.readline().strip().replace("[TC]",''))
```

still can't, and look like

```
1880 21
1882 13
1884 5
1886 97
1888 89
1890 81
1892 73
1894 65
1896 57
```

so how can i fix the data jump

Comment: Have you tried to print out what ser.readline() returns?

Comment: A line of your file is empty and `string` becomes an empty string. It is often the last line (trailing carriage return).

Comment: @Lafexlos yes, it's print [TC]4915 31[TC] , but use print string.split(" ")  it would print ['\r[TC]4915', '31[TC]\n']

Comment: @muraveill Uhh.....sorry i'm not know what do you mean :(

Comment: @W.Shawn Try you example with `string = ""` and see that you get the same error. Use `print(string)` in your loop to see if it actually happens with your real data. You can only extract `T[1]` if `T` is not empty.

Comment: Printing is _almost always_ the easiest debugging method for python. If you are getting an error at TC[1] then print TC right before that to see what that holds.

Comment: Also you can chain functions. `ser.readline().strip().replace()`. When doing it just be careful that function actually returns someting.

Comment: @muraveill i try to use print(string).it's print 4919 15 like that

Comment: @W.Shawn Try instead to `print(string == '')` and see if it returns True.

Comment: @muraveill Oh~no,it's false,so i need translate data to string?

Comment: @W.Shawn print TC before printing TC[1] and show the result.

Comment: @muraveill print TC it's print this ['2315', '31']

Comment: @W.Shawn I am not sure I understand. There is only one line in your file ?? You need to print all of them in the loop, for one is empty.